# Debug message "Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function" using QtQuick

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-quick, qt5.4

I am just learning QtQuick and have run into something that I can't explain.  Just to provide some background I'm using the following:

- QtCreator 3.1.2 OpenSource
- Qt 5.4 debug libraries built from source using MinGW-64 with posix threads and SEH

My QML looks like the following:

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 500
    height: 200

    GridLayout {
        id: mainGrid
        rows: 3
        columns: 2
        columnSpacing: 2
        rowSpacing: 2

        Label {
            text: "First Name:"
        }

        TextField {

        }
    }
}
```

The example appears to run fine but I receive a debug message in QtCreator's 'Application Output' console with the following text:

"Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function."

I did some testing by adding one component to the Window at a time and discovered that the Label component appears to be causing this message to appear.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and/or know how I can get this to go away?  And should I be concerned about this message?  I worry about this causing a fatal exception down the road in my application.

Addtional Information:

After finding a nice post by Dennis Yurichev in regards to how one might debug this error using gdb (found [here](http://dennisyurichev.blogspot.com/2013/05/warning-invalid-parameter-passed-to-c.html)), I was able to produce the following stacktrace.  I have not yet went through the stacktrace to draw any conclusions, but I wanted to post it in case anyone is interested in helping me figure this out:

```
Breakpoint 1, 0x000007fefdbba9cc in OutputDebugStringA () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
(gdb) bt
#0  0x000007fefdbba9cc in OutputDebugStringA () from C:\Windows\system32\KernelBase.dll
#1  0x000007feff5b2478 in msvcrt!_assert () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#2  0x000007feff5b249b in msvcrt!_invalid_parameter () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#3  0x000007feff590ef2 in pow () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#4  0x000007feff575b78 in msvcrt!_localtime64 () from C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
#5  0x000000000d78a617 in DaylightSavingTA (t=-62198737200000) at jsruntime\qv4dateobject.cpp:291
#6  0x000000000d78a6b8 in LocalTime (t=-62198737200000) at jsruntime\qv4dateobject.cpp:306
#7  0x000000000d78f2b5 in QV4::DatePrototype::method_getFullYear (ctx=0x22cc30) at jsruntime\qv4dateobject.cpp:864
#8  0x000000000d797823 in QV4::BuiltinFunction::call (that=0x383300, callData=0x18760290) at jsruntime\qv4functionobject.cpp:565
#9  0x000000000d941107 in QV4::Object::call (this=0x383300, d=0x18760290)
    at ../../include/QtQml/5.4.0/QtQml/private/../../../../../src/qml/jsruntime/qv4object_p.h:278
#10 0x000000000d7d1c37 in QV4::Runtime::callProperty (context=0x156e0120, name=0x2e1dd0, callData=0x18760290) at jsruntime\qv4runtime.cpp:930
#11 0x000000000d7c92b0 in QV4::Moth::VME::run (this=0x22d987, context=0x156e0120, code=0x1942d6f8 "", storeJumpTable=0x0) at jsruntime\qv4vme_moth.cpp:365
#12 0x000000000d7cd248 in QV4::Moth::VME::exec (ctxt=0x156e0120, code=0x1942d468 "\017\217|\r") at jsruntime\qv4vme_moth.cpp:734
#13 0x000000000d7b88df in QV4::QmlBindingWrapper::call (that=0x389680) at jsruntime\qv4script.cpp:108
#14 0x000000000d941107 in QV4::Object::call (this=0x389680, d=0x18760230)
    at ../../include/QtQml/5.4.0/QtQml/private/../../../../../src/qml/jsruntime/qv4object_p.h:278
#15 0x000000000d7b9ad7 in QV4::Script::run (this=0x194567a0) at jsruntime\qv4script.cpp:300
#16 0x000000000d8133d3 in QQmlScriptData::scriptValueForContext (this=0x19416530, parentCtxt=0x2b71ac70) at qml\qqmltypeloader.cpp:2643
#17 0x000000000d85247d in QQmlObjectCreator::create (this=0x22de20, subComponentIndex=-1, parent=0x0, interrupt=0x0) at qml\qqmlobjectcreator.cpp:216
#18 0x000000000d857fa1 in QQmlObjectCreator::createInstance (this=0x194f2190, index=2, parent=0x19481210, isContextObject=false)
    at qml\qqmlobjectcreator.cpp:1091
#19 0x000000000d855c62 in QQmlObjectCreator::setPropertyBinding (this=0x194f2190, property=0x194144e8, binding=0x194f1bbc) at qml\qqmlobjectcreator.cpp:774
#20 0x000000000d855751 in QQmlObjectCreator::setupBindings (this=0x194f2190, bindingsToSkip=...) at qml\qqmlobjectcreator.cpp:733
#21 0x000000000d8594e1 in QQmlObjectCreator::populateInstance (this=0x194f2190, index=1, instance=0x194f2790, bindingTarget=0x194f2790,
    valueTypeProperty=0x0, bindingsToSkip=...) at qml\qqmlobjectcreator.cpp:1348
#22 0x000000000d85883b in QQmlObjectCreator::createInstance (this=0x194f2190, index=1, parent=0x194f2790, isContextObject=false)
    at qml\qqmlobjectcreator.cpp:1184
#23 0x000000000d855c62 in QQmlObjectCreator::setPropertyBinding (this=0x194f2190, property=0x19482d18, binding=0x194f1ac8) at qml\qqmlobjectcreator.cpp:774
#24 0x000000000d855751 in QQmlObjectCreator::setupBindings (this=0x194f2190, bindingsToSkip=...) at qml\qqmlobjectcreator.cpp:733
#25 0x000000000d8594e1 in QQmlObjectCreator::populateInstance (this=0x194f2190, index=0, instance=0x0, bindingTarget=0xbaadf00dbaadf00d,
    valueTypeProperty=0x0, bindingsToSkip=...) at qml\qqmlobjectcreator.cpp:1348
#26 0x000000000d85883b in QQmlObjectCreator::createInstance (this=0x194f2190, index=0, parent=0x0, isContextObject=true) at qml\qqmlobjectcreator.cpp:1184
#27 0x000000000d852564 in QQmlObjectCreator::create (this=0x194f2190, subComponentIndex=-1, parent=0x0, interrupt=0x0) at qml\qqmlobjectcreator.cpp:222
#28 0x000000000d7f7076 in QQmlComponentPrivate::beginCreate (this=0x193af700, context=0x193ae530) at qml\qqmlcomponent.cpp:880
#29 0x000000000d7f6cc2 in QQmlComponent::beginCreate (this=0x193af6c0, publicContext=0x193a17c0) at qml\qqmlcomponent.cpp:829
#30 0x000000000d7f6c23 in QQmlComponent::create (this=0x193af6c0, context=0x193a17c0) at qml\qqmlcomponent.cpp:789
#31 0x000000000d84b38f in QQmlApplicationEnginePrivate::_q_finishLoad (this=0x155b4ab0, o=0x193af6c0) at qml\qqmlapplicationengine.cpp:130
#32 0x000000000d84b13a in QQmlApplicationEnginePrivate::startLoad (this=0x155b4ab0, url=..., data=..., dataFlag=false) at qml\qqmlapplicationengine.cpp:109
#33 0x000000000d84b68e in QQmlApplicationEngine::load (this=0x22fd90, url=...) at qml\qqmlapplicationengine.cpp:250
#34 0x0000000000401589 in qMain (argc=1, argv=0x15726a00) at ..\learnqtquick\main.cpp:9
#35 0x0000000000402e7d in WinMain () at qtmain_win.cpp:112
#36 0x00000000004013b5 in __tmainCRTStartup ()
#37 0x00000000004014c8 in WinMainCRTStartup ()
```

Additional debug information:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: C:\Users\Chris\programming\build-learnqtquick-MinGW64-Debug\debug\learnqtquick.exe
[New Thread 5044.0x1284]
warning: QML debugging is enabled. Only use this in a safe environment.

[New Thread 5044.0x11dc]
[New Thread 5044.0x6ac]
[New Thread 5044.0x13e8]

Breakpoint 1, QV4::DateObject::Data::Data (this=0x3c48c0, engine=0x183560a0, date=...) at jsruntime/qv4dateobject_p.h:51
51                  value = date;
(gdb) print date->val
$1 = 4410089336627904512
(gdb) print date->doubleValue()
$2 = -62198737200000
```

Code suspected to be in error from `qv4value_p.h`

```
double doubleValue() const {
    Q_ASSERT(isDouble());
    union {
        quint64 i;
        double d;
    } v;
    v.i = val ^ NaNEncodeMask;
    return v.d;
}
```

...specifically, after the assignment `v.i = val ^ NaNEncodeMask`, the following is the result in the gdb debugger:

```
(gdb) print v.d
$7 = -62198737200000
(gdb) print v.i
$8 = 14036674277620695040
```

I don't understand how this union could ever produce a correct conversion of a large number from quint64 to double consistently??  Can anyone explain what they original author of this code was trying to achieve?

Additional information discovered 2/28/2015 -
Apparently the information above only applies to debug builds.  I built a release version of this version of Qt5.4 and could not duplicate the issue.  Then switching back to a debug build I again re-created the issue.  Thus, I will not be filing a bug report for this issue.  Instead, I am searching for an explanation related to debugging in the MinGW64 compiler suite.

Comment: Afaik, Qt is not stable on MinGW-64. You might have run into a bug. There is not too much we can do. Since it may be an issue with the exactly version and configuration of your compiled Qt, and MinGW-64, it is very hard to tell anything. I think  the only thing that can help you is a debugger or the Qt Forums. Sorry =/

Comment: That's kind of what I was afraid of.  I tried running this with the debugger in QtCreator but the application continues to run right through this log message and everything appears to run fine.  I guess it's time to become a little more familiar with the GDB debugger and see if i can figure out where this error is coming from.

Comment: It looks like some type of numeric overflow where a negative value is passed to the LocalTime method.  Looking through the source, it looks like somehow the conversion of DateObject.value to double via Value.asDouble() is not behaving correctly.  Unfortunately, this source is a mess and I don't have much background in this code so I'm just searching for anything that's glaringly wrong.

Comment: I'll take a look at the Qt sources. I'll keep you updated.

Comment: I believe the problem is while instancing `DateObject` at `qv4dateobject_p.h`. I work only on Linux, so I can not really trace the issue. Is it possible to you to insert break points at the constructors of `DateObject::Data` struct? They are at the line 48. I'm using the Windows sources published at the Qt download page.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion and post again soon regarding the results of my testing.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira - I've edited the post to include a bit more debugging information.  I'm still struggling to understand how this value might have rolled past max into a negative value (through a type conversion or other means...)  Something in the doubleValue() method appears to be the culprit...

Comment: Very strange. I have no idea what it means. If this is really the problem, I don't think it will ever crash your application. But who knows? Have you tested it on a 32 bit build?

Comment: Have not tried it on 32-bit build but I may be able to find the time to start a fresh build sometime in the next week.  I think this may be a classic case of a programmer trying to get too "cute" with managing memory and stepping on his own toes.

"Never pursue efficiency at the expense of clarity" - (McCann, 1997)